# Is the National Aviation Authority the same as the Civil Aviation Authority?

Tags: safety, terminology

Are the NAA (National aviation authority) and the CAA (Civil aviation authority) the same organisation? According Wikipedia it looks like they are the same organisation.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Akiyo. What country are you asking about?

Comment: Which country do you mean?

Comment: Hello Dan, I meant in general, if there is any difference between does two? Or is it exactly the same type of organisation just called differently in some countries?

Answer (score 3):

The terms National Aviation Authority and Civil Aviation Authority are indeed two generic terms to describe the same thing - the government organisation responsible for managing non-military aviation within a country.

It's worth noting that the specifics of how the organisation works and what it regulates is down to each country, so the terms are broad and generic. For example, Iceland doesn't have any kind of specific CAA - rather, those roles are performed by the Icelandic Transport Authority.

In addition, it wouldn't really be right to refer to a countries authority as *the* National Aviation Authority or *the* Civil Aviation Authority (Unless that's what they've called themselves).

For example, the FAA is an example of *a* National Aviation Authority, it isn't known as *the* National Aviation Authority. The UK's Civil Aviation Authority is *the* Civil Aviation Authority *in the UK* and an example of *a* National Aviation Authority